# Keeps generating new number out of random.randrange after input

Tags: python, function, random, integer

Basically my program is a number guessing game include stuff such as number of rounds, will identify if that number has been said or not already, if the number is out of the range (1 and 100).

After making a function (checks if its an integer )so i don't repeat my code in while loops, my code seems to generate a new number to guess after every guess inputed and when typed in the same number again it will notice and return saying that the number has already been entered before but then will say if the number is to high or not which I don't want. Any help on how to fix this is greatly appreaciated.

```
# Higher / Lower version 4
# Basic program works has loop but does not ask for num of rounds or store best score and says if number was already entered.
import random

# List for already said inputs
tried_num = []

# Score
best_score = 25

# Rounds
rounds_played = 0
valid_round = False

# Checks numeric input is valid
def int_check(question,min,max):
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        try:
            response = int(input(question))
            if response < min or response > max:
                print("\n Whoops!  Please enter an INTEGER between {} and {}".format(min,max))
            else:
                valid = True
                return(response)

        except ValueError:
            print("You did not enter an INTEGER.  Please try again")


rounds_wanted = int_check("How many rounds would you like to play? (1 - 10): ",1,10)

while rounds_played < rounds_wanted:

    # Generate random integer
    gen_num = random.randrange(1,100)
    print(gen_num)

    # Guess
    num_guesses = 0
    guess = int_check("Guess the number between 1 and 100: ",1,100)

    if guess not in tried_num:
        num_guesses += 1
        tried_num.append(guess)
    else:
        print("You already guessed that number, Try a differnet one \n")


    # Num of guesses till round ends
    if num_guesses > 26:
        print("You Lose! You have used up your 25 guesses, the number was %s" % gen_num)


    elif guess > gen_num:
        print("Your guess was to high , Try a lower number \n")

    elif guess < gen_num:
        print("Your guess was to low , Try a higher number \n")

    elif num_guesses == 1:
        rounds_played = rounds_played + 1
        print("Congratulations you have won, you guessed the number in 1 Guess!!")

    else:
        rounds_played = rounds_played + 1
        print("Congratulations you have won, you guessed the number in %s guesses \n" % num_guesses)

    # Update Best Score if number of guesses is lower
    if num_guesses < best_score:
        best_score = num_guesses

if best_score < 26 :
    print("Your best score was: %s!" % best_score)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you have a loop to control the playing of the selected number of rounds, each time around the body of that loop you are only asking for a single guess. You really need a loop inside the existing loop to control the playing of a single round. You can see the nested loop structure in the revised code below (with a third nested loop to handle repeated guesses).

```
import random

def int_check(question,min,max):
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        try:
            response = int(input(question))
            if response < min or response > max:
                print("\n Whoops!  Please enter an INTEGER between {} and {}".format(min,max))
            else:
                valid = True
                return(response)

        except ValueError:
            print("You did not enter an INTEGER.  Please try again")

rounds_wanted = 20
max_guesses = 5
successes = 0
for round_number in range(rounds_wanted):
    gen_num = random.randrange(1,100)
    print("+++ Game", round_number+1, "- secret is", gen_num)
    previous_guesses = []
    guess = None    
    for guess_number in range(max_guesses):
        # get the next guess
        while not previous_guesses or guess in previous_guesses:
            guess = int_check("Guess {}: ".format(guess_number+1), 1, 100)
            if guess in previous_guesses:
                print("You already guessed", guess, "- please try again")
            else:
                previous_guesses.append(guess)
                break
        if guess == gen_num:
            successes += 1
            print("Well done - you got it!")
            break
        else:
            print("Sorry - try again")
    else:
        print("I won this one!")
    print("Successes so far:", successes, "out of", round_number+1)
print("Thanks for playing")
```

Comment: Sorry im new at python how would i put that into my code with my variables

Comment: I've rewritten my answer to show you the (or rather a) correct program structure. You will notice that I've made both the number of rounds and the guesses per round variables, so it's easy to lower them for testing.